# Naming regex groups in Python

Tags: python, regex

I came across the website rubular.com, and their example regex was :

```
(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})
```

where the months, day, and year encased in the < > tags each group with that name.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do that in Python since I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that using `(?P<group_name>...)`:

```
(?P<month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<day>\d{1,2})\/(?P<year>\d{4})
```

See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

To do so in Python, you would prefix the named group with the letter 'P' like so:

```
import re

match = re.search('(?P<month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<day>\d{1,2})\/(?P<year>\d{4})', '01/02/2000')

print match.group('day')
print match.group('month')
print match.group('year')
```

The [documentation page for Regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) doesn't clearly highlight it, but you are looking for the section on

```
(?P<name>...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
(?P<month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<day>\d{1,2})\/(?P<year>\d{4})
```